# Cannot create a sandbox

Tags: sandbox

We have Enterprise Edition of Salesforce and I have successfully created a sandbox in Common Ground, listed under the "Data Management" section of "Setup."

However, we are now using the Non-Profit Starter Pack and I do not see any Sandbox option anywhere in the back end.

Am I looking in the wrong place? Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but hasn't Common Ground been retired and given an end-of-life date of March 2014. - http://kellpartners.com/kell-labs/50-let-s-talk-about-common-ground

Answer (score 2):

Common Gound and Non-Profit Starter Pack have no impact on your ability to create a sandbox. You might be using the newer setup menu now.

Look under Deploy section of Setup.

Note that Enterprise Edition can have only one sandbox unless you'd paid for extra sandboxes.

Comment: Actually, Foundation-granted Enterprise Edition instances (which Virginia's instance almost certainly is) come with 6 Developer sandboxes and 1 Developer Pro. 

But yes, likely to be new vs. old Setup menu. Type "Sandbox" in the setup search box at the top of the left-hand setup navigation and it'll turn up, whichever Setup menu you're using.